# Python: String to Regex Pattern

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string of characters.

```
charstr = "SZR"
```

Suppose that the character Z is a loaded character and can represent S, P, Q, W, or R

I want to write a function get_regex(charstr) which takes charstr as an input and returns a regular expression string.
Which can then be used to find patterns in other strings.

The following code should not results in answer = 'None', since SZR matches SRR and SWR, which are in SQSRRSWR.

```
charstr = "SZR"
answer = re.search(get_regex(charstr), 'SQSRRSWR')
```

I have tried the following but it won't work. Any suggestions?

```
import re
def get_regex(charstr):
    charstr = re.sub("Z", "[SPQWR]{1}", charstr) # Z: can be S,P,Q,W, or R
    #The line directly below this was in my original post.  I have commmented it out and the function now works properly.
    #charstr = "\'\'\'^ " + charstr + "\'\'\'"    # Results in '''^ S[SPQWR]{1}R'''
    return charstr

charstr = "SZR"
answer = re.search(get_regex(charstr), 'SQSRRSWR')
print(answer)                                    # Results in None
```

Comment: commenting out the line that sets `charstr` to `'''^ S[SPQWR]{1}R'''` makes your regex work. Is there any significance to that part?

Comment: You have a space after the caret, plus you're including the single quotes in the string. Why? The regex string you're after is `^S[SPQWR]R`, so why not just `'^{}'.format(charstr)`?

Comment: I thought you had to specify a regular expression in that way.  Thanks.  I have commented out that line in my code to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to be pretty close to working.  If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, this works:

```
import re

def get_regex(charstr):
    charstr = re.sub("Z", "[SPQWR]", charstr) # Z: can be S,P,Q,W, or R
    return charstr

charstr = "SZR"
if re.search(get_regex(charstr), 'SQSRRSWR'):
    print("yep it matched")
else:
    print("nope it does not match")

charstr = "SXR"
if re.search(get_regex(charstr), 'SQSRRSWR'):
    print("yep it matched")
else:
    print("nope it does not match")
```

results in:

```
yep it matched
nope it does not match
```

Which looks to be what you are trying to do.  I took out the {1} since that is implied.  Just toss a comment in if it doesn't seem right and I'll update this answer.